ArrayOutOfBoundException 2-D Array Java
I have an ArrayList of type String called simpleText that holds different number of sentences depending on the user. I have another array of type char called eachSentence which is 2D, that stores each character of each sentence. Row one is the first sentence and so on. After the first iteration I get ArrayOutOfBoundException.
ArrayList<String> simpleText = new ArrayList<String>();
char[][] eachSentence = new char[simpleText.size()][];


public void setStringArray() {
    String sentence;
    for (int i = 0; i < simpleText.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < simpleText.get(i).length(); j++) {
            sentence = simpleText.get(i);
            eachSentence[i][j] = sentence.charAt(j);
        }
    }
}

I debugged the code and it seems fine before the next iteration. The debugger tells me that eachSentence[i][j] = sentence.charAt(j); is the problem. Please help.

Looks to me that you have not assigned a value to the second dimension of array eachSentence. Do you think that the array size is automatically allocated?

While you can add elements to an ArrayList, you cannot do the same with arrays. Arrays are fixed size.

I wonder this code is not throwing a NullPointerException ?! There must be more code between first and second snippet if you are getting ArrayOutOfBoundException.

In Java, a two dimensional array can be thought of as an array of arrays, i.e. an array where each element of the array is an array. Hence a two dimensional array can be a jagged array, i.e. each element can be a different sized array.
In the code in your question, you need to explicitly assign a value to the second dimension of array eachSentence but you are not. Since each sentence can have a different length, I suggest creating a new array for each sentence and adding that new array to eachSentence.
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sentences {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> simpleText = new ArrayList<String>();
        simpleText.add("This is the first sentence.");
        simpleText.add("This sentence is the second sentence.");
        simpleText.add("This will be the last sentence.");
        char[][] eachSentence = new char[simpleText.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < simpleText.size(); i++) {
            String aSentence = simpleText.get(i);
            int len = aSentence.length();
            char[] letters = new char[len];
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                letters[j] = aSentence.charAt(j);
            }
            eachSentence[i] = letters;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < eachSentence.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < eachSentence[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(eachSentence[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

Running the above code produces the following output:
T h i s   i s   t h e   f i r s t   s e n t e n c e . 
T h i s   s e n t e n c e   i s   t h e   s e c o n d   s e n t e n c e . 
T h i s   w i l l   b e   t h e   l a s t   s e n t e n c e .


T h i s   i s   t h e   e n d   a s   w e   k n o w   i t.
